# Creating Arrays in C containing data from R data frame

Tags: c, arrays, r

I have a simple data set in R which contains one column with country number codes (all ints) and another column containing the country areas (all doubles) of each respective country.

(edit): A sample R data frame would look like this:

[R sample data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz2rs.png)

I pass this data frame into an R function, which in turn uses .Call to call a C function. In this C function, I want to get an int array containing the list of country codes and a separate double array containing the list of country areas. So using the example R data frame, I want to get an int array containing 1,2,3 and a a double array containing 50.5, 63.4 and 120.2.

C code:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

SEXP trialfuncc(SEXP countryn, SEXP area) {

    //initialize variables
    int i, j, k, len = Rf_length(countryn);
    int countrylist[len];
    double arealist[len];


    //check for data type for country code
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {

        if(TYPEOF(VECTOR_ELT(countryn, i))!= INTSXP) {
            /*error*/
            error_return("Input data must be of type integer");
        }
        //else add to the array
        else {
            countrylist[i] = *INTEGER(VECTOR_ELT(countryn, i));
        }

    };

    //Should I be initializing a pointer and doing this instead?
    //countrylist = INTEGER(countryn);


    //check for data type for country area
    for (j = 0; j<len; j++) {


        if(TYPEOF(VECTOR_ELT(area, j)) != REALSXP) {
            /*error*/
            error_return("Input data must be of type double");
        }
        //else add to the array
        else {
            arealist[j] = *REAL(VECTOR_ELT(area, j));
        }

    };

    //Should I be initializing a pointer and doing this instead?
    //arealist = REAL(area);


    //test: Print this array to check whether countrylist is produced
    for (k=0; k < len; k++) {
        printf("%i\n",countrylist[k]);
    }

}
```

R Code:

```
dyn.load("trialfunc.so")

#test function

trialfuncr <- function(data) { #where data is the data frame
  #single data set for country name (first column)
  countryn <- as.list(data[,1])
  #single data set for area (second column)
  area <- as.list(data[,2])
  #Call the C function
  .Call("trialfuncc",countryn,area)
}
```

I can produce the .so file, but when I source the R code and run the function trialfuncr with a dataset, this does not work. R just crashes and restarts. No explanation whatsoever.

My issues may stem from the fact that I don't understand the R internal structures very well and I also don't understand what functions INTEGER and REAL do (can't seem to google for documentation). Any simple explanation/links/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Anyway to convince you to give [Rcpp](http://rcpp.org) a shot?

Comment: I suggest including a small data set with the desired answer so that people can actually try to run your code and obtain that answer.

Comment: There are many issues with your code. For first, the C function doesn't return anything, although it declares to return a `SEXP`. Secondly, I don't get the `as.list` before calling C. Why do you coerce it to a list? Then, you fill static arrays: their values will be likely erased once you exit from the function. Try reading this link: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html. I found it useful to get a grasp of the R/C interface.

Comment: @Coatless Believe me I would love to! I'm just working with a lot of code that is already in C and I'm not sure how moving to C++ would be like. (I'm experimenting with using some C calculations I have in R.

Comment: @MarkMiller I added an example data set!

Comment: @nicola Hey thanks for your help. I'm not sure what I am supposed to return if I just want to test to see if I can produce the desired array within C (this is a simple test to see if I can get the data from R and then use C to do more complicated calculations with it). Maybe I should return R_NilValue?
I used coercion because I am under the impression that in order to deal with an R data set in C, I have to use the function VECTOR_ELT (all the examples I've seen seem to use it). When I tried the function without coercion, it said I could only use VECTOR_ELT on a list- hence coercion.

Comment: Returning `R_NilValue` is a good idea for a test. `VECTOR_ELT` extracts an element of a list. For instance, if `a` is a list, the C equivalent of the R `a[[1]]` would be `VECTOR_ELT(a,0)`. If you pass say an integer vector to C, with `INTEGER(vec)` you get a `int *` pointer to the values of `vec`. Say you define `int *p = INTEGER(vec);` then with `p[0]`, `p[1]`,...,`p[length(vec)-1]` you can get the values. Read the link I provided, it's very useful.

Comment: @nicola Thanks for explaining! Really helpful stuff. I will go check out the link too.